# Javascript, looping through gridview checking hidden values

Tags: javascript, .net

I need some help :). Im trying to build a Javascript that goes through a gridview on my page and for each row checks the hiddenvalue that is stored in a certain cell of that row. It should then check this against a filtervalue and if it doesnt match hide the row in question.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please show the html that is a result of your gridview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not the most elegant, this should get you started in the right direction:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HideEvenValueRows() {
        var tGrid = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID%>');
        for (var i = 0; i < tGrid.rows.length; ++i) {
            var inputs = tGrid.rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; ++j) {
                if (inputs[j].type == "hidden") {
                    var k = inputs[j].value * 1;
                    if (k % 2 == 0) {
                        tGrid.rows[i].style.visibility = "collapse";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```